# Swift 3 append to UIImageView

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uiimageview

I have a `UIImageView` and I want to append there images coming from a remote `URL`

Up to now it works fine with only one image.
I just set `cell.related.image` to the new image and I return always 1 to the `collectionView`

How can I switch to appending an array of images?

Is there a way to do the appending in a function? 
Do I need always to do the appending inside `collectionView` ?

I want to do it inside an event listener in the future

```
var img_uls = ["url1" , "url2", "url3"]

func append_image(_ path: String, _ cell: RelatedCollectionViewCell) {
    let url = URL(string: path)

    DispatchQueue.global().async {
        let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url!) //make sure your image in this url does exist, otherwise unwrap in a if let check / try-catch
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            cell.related.image = UIImage(data: data!)
        }
    }
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return img_uls.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {



    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "RelatedCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! RelatedCollectionViewCell

    append_image(img_uls[indexPath.row], cell);


    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just have the array of String which contains Url of your image and pass it as in `numberOfItems` Method like this

```
var img_uls = ["url1" , "url2", "url3"]
//array of strings containing urls

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return img_uls.count 
}
```

Now you have to iterate your array `img_uls`, So that you can fetch Url from array and fetch the images and set in collectionView cell. So, do it like this

```
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "RelatedCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! RelatedCollectionViewCell

    append_image(img_uls[indexPath.row], cell);

// indexPath.row starts from (0) and goes to (img_uls.count - 1)

    return cell
}
```

Now you want to append the image into `images` array

```
var images = NSMutableData()

func append_image(_ path: String, _ cell: RelatedCollectionViewCell) {

    let url = URL(string: path)

    DispatchQueue.global().async {
        let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url!) //make sure your image in this url does exist, otherwise unwrap in a if let check / try-catch
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
           images.appendData(data)
           cell.related.image = UIImage(data: data!)
        }
    }
}
```

Instead of using your own append method, and handling that append and all, you can use [Kingfisher](https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher) or [Haenke](https://github.com/Haneke/Haneke). They are lightweight and moreover manages caching. And hence your scrolling will be fast.

Comment: How do I append to `images` array?

My append_image function accepts a string and a cell but you are calling it like `append_image(images[indexPath.row], cell);`

Can you provide also the new `append_image` function please?

Comment: Where do you have your whole set of url of images which you want to populate in collectionview?

Comment: `var img_uls = ["url1" , "url2", "url3"]` in the view conroller

Comment: There are a coupe of errors:
First in `images.append(data) // appending` i get `Argument type 'Data?' does not conform to expected type 'AnyObject'`

Then in `append_image(images[indexPath.row], cell);` i get ` 'AnyObject' is not convertible to 'String'; did you mean to use 'as!' to force downcast?`

Comment: Can you post a complete answer please? 
Also you are not using `images` array at any place only appending to it

Comment: Though i solved your errors. Unable to understand your why to use `images`. Do you want caching the images and not to load asynchronously every time? If you want it use these libraries mentioned here.

Comment: No I don't want to do that. At least not now. It was there because of a previous example. I can remove the images array right?

Comment: Then your append function will be useless. Not useless, I mean you won't be appending then

Comment: I don't get it. Forget about that array and caching I just want to display an array of urls to my UIImageView. How can I do that please? Why do I need to do this always inside the collectionView function. can this be done from outside? Please post an updated answer

Comment: So remove that array and don't append anything into it. Why do I need to do this always inside the collectionView function---- Because here you iterate your `img_uls`(same as like for loop) but here you are loading your collectionViewCell also. That's why you have to do here only

Comment: Is there a way to do this from outside please? There will be more images coming from an event listener for ex? How can I move this outside collectionView? I come from Javascript and these things doesn't make sense to me :/

Comment: append method can't be move outside of collectionview method

Comment: Then how do I load new images to UIImageView. for ex user click a button and i insert a new image

Comment: Call `collectionview.reloadData()` after you insert new image on button click

Comment: Can you please check my updated question. Can you make an example of appending this image `https://i.ytimg.com/vi/kWxHV9jkwSA/hqdefault.jpg`  from outside, like faking a click event

The whole idea is that when the app starts 10 images will be loaded. then more will be added

Comment: From where these 10images are coming from, probably you are calling some api? To append use [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24002733/add-an-element-to-an-array-in-swift). Probably i didn't got what you want to achieve.

Comment: exactly from api. When I'm saying append I mean appending the images to the UIImageView not to a variable. How can I put these images` var img_uls = ["url1" , "url2", "url3"]` to my UIImageView?

Comment: Call the api from where you get these 10 images and in the [closure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29824488/when-to-use-closures-in-swift) of api(i.e where you get response),say you will get 10-15images url's, append them to `img_uls` and call collectionview.reloadData() after appending. Do these steps and you are done.

Comment: Can you please update your answer. my `UIImageView` instance is this: `@IBOutlet weak var related: UIImageView!` and assume the array of urls is this `var img_uls = ["url1" , "url2", "url3"]`

Answer (score 0):

Create a imageUrlArray variable of String which will hold the remote image URLs, then return the count of the array from your `numberOfItemsInSection` method. In `collectionView:cellForItemAt` function get the Url to display from the array using imageArray[indexPath.row] and pass the Url to the `append_image(_ path: String, _ cell: RelatedCollectionViewCell)` function. Better use third party image loading library like [KingFisher](https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher) or [Nuke](https://github.com/kean/Nuke) to better handle Asynchronous image downloading and caching.

```
class Example1: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource {
 var imageArray: [String] = []

  override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
  }

  func updateImages(_ images: [String]) {
   self.imageArray = images 
  }

  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return imageArray.count 
  }

 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "RelatedCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! RelatedCollectionViewCell
    //append_image(imageArray[indexPath.row], cell)

    //Using Kingfisher 
    let url = imageArray[indexPath.row]
    cell.imageView.kf.setImage(with: url, placeholder: nil, options: [.transition(.fade(1))])
    return cell
  }
}
```

Comment: Is it better to use a library for this?
Can you show me how do i implement kingfisher. I'm pretty new in swift

Comment: click on the link https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher and checkout the demo folder and documentation. If you have not used cocoapods before then visit this https://www.raywenderlich.com/156971/cocoapods-tutorial-swift-getting-started as well on how to use third party libraries in iOS projects.